# Right aligning buttons/ content in a header and footer divs

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I am trying to aligns some buttons right on my header and footer. but currently they are just somewhat right aligned. The code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/fXzX2/ and you can see the "demo" here: dev.chatterr.com.

Idk if I should use something like:

```
    width: 1352px;
```

or:

```
    float: right;
```

or what. What do you think that I should do to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
div.nav {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Change that to

```
div.nav {
    display: table-cell;
    float: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

in your css

Comment: What about the footer? Also that removes the vertical align?

Comment: Well siddhartha what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

how exactly are you willing to align them?

1. left aligned ?
2. center aligned ?

You should clear that :)

Look, you have to choose the css alignment methods depending on what the element is itself and also how other elements before and after that are styled.

You can do that using following styles :

- margin
- vertical-align
- line-height
- text-align
- float

... etc.

I think you should Read these articles which are useful for any web developer Or designer.

http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Anyway, giving a float:right and clear:both would solve the alignment of your nav.
And about vertical alignment like here, it'd be kind of confusing to tell someone what you want or try to do. It'd be a good practice to first design your theme or website in Adobe Photoshop and then show that anywhere needed like here.

Check your jsfiddle.

Comment: I would like it Right aligned, and vertically centered.